# unable to read csv file on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df=pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/tom/Desktop/misc/number-of-motor-vehicles-2018-census-csv.csv")
df
```

the above 4 lines are my code and  im getting the error as shown below

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C:/Users/tom/Desktop/misc/number-of-motor-vehicles-2018-census- 
 csv.csv does not exist: 'C:/Users/tom/Desktop/misc/number-of-motor-vehicles-2018-census-csv.csv'
```

i tried removing "r"
i tried front and back slash
single and double quotes...plz help me out

Comment: I don't have Windows.. but isn't it supposed to be `C://Users/` instead of `C:/Users/` ?

Comment: @dgan the `r` handles the escape chars. tom can you print `os.listdir(r"C:/Users/tom/Desktop/misc/")` and paste it here

Comment: well, the error is clear, file can't be found, try creating some other files in the same path and try to read them, and figure out why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that the file does not have a second extension (possibly .txt)? This might happen when e.g. saving a file with Notepad and appending `.csv` to the file name but disregarding the dropdown box "Save as type" ...

You could try

- go to the “View” tab on the ribbon in Windows Explorer and activate the “File name extensions” box in the Show/hide section
- hit Win+R, type 'cmd' and try `Dir C:\Users\tom\Desktop\misc\`
- use the function `os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Tobi\Desktop\misc')` in python